# How do I auto-populate the "Purpose" field when accepting donations through PayPal?

Tags: paypal

The wildlife conservation organization that I volunteer for has partnered up with an existing non-profit that will accept donations on our behalf while we wait on our non-profit status to be approved.  Their PayPal donation page has a field in the header area labeled "Purpose" that I would like to auto-populate with the name of our organization when they click the donate button from our website in order to alleviate any confusion as to which organization the donor is donating to.  I found tutorials to auto-populate other fields on the form such as name and address, but these techniques don't seem to work for the "Purpose" field.  Can anyone help me solve this issue?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The field name is called `item_name` - if you pass a value in your PayPal arguments with this field pre-populated then you will see that the "Purpose" field is now filled with it's value.